# Is the usage "can able to" wrong? I believe it's wrong. But where can I find some reference on the same?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, subcontinental-english, can-vs-be-able

I hear a lot of people use 'can able to' in their daily talk. I believe it's entirely wrong. Both 'can' and 'able to' hold the same meaning. Where do I get more information on the same and also the exact places where I should use 'can' and where I should use 'able to'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Indian English. If you are talking to the rest of the world you should check out
[Mind your English](http://www.mindyourenglish.com/articles/essential-english/2010/01/26/indian-english.html). Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: I do want to talk with the rest of the world. :-) Thanks for the link.

Comment: Well, I would say "it's a common *mistake* in Indian English", but… :-)

Comment: It at best be as @ShreevatsaR said, "a common *mistake* in Indian English", not even an *Indianism*, certainly not *Indian English* in its correct form. No one would deliberately use this expression to make himself understood to an Indian English speaker. I'm not sure what you meant by 'Otherwise it's fine,' was that sarcasm?

Comment: Link is dead now

Comment: It is not "Indian English" or "common mistake in Indian English". It is a common mistake in English spoken in some parts of India.

Comment: @Cindi This is precisely the reason that answers which do not reproduce any of the link's content are frowned upon. Could you update your answer, please?

Answer (score 3):

This may be common in Indian English. However, it's certainly not accepted as Standard English because, as you say, *can* and *be able to* have the same meaning.

Because *able to* isn't a verb but part of an adjectival phrase, it requires a verb; but as it's adjectival that verb is *be,* not *can*.