# Future tense of the word "Can"

Tags: verbs, tenses, modal-verbs, future

What is the future tense of the word *can*?
One way to express it is "will be able to", but what is actually the future tense of "can" ?

Comment: Can is a modal verb and modal verbs have only two forms, present tense and past tense. As there is no infinitive,  they can't form future tense, and as there is no past participle they can't form perfect forms. I think any website about modals explains this.

Comment: I was mistaken. Most websites don't mention the lacking infinitive and past participle at all. In online grammar nothing is perfect. Websites can't replace a real grammar in book form..

Comment: Related **1.** [Using “can” to express future ability](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133687/using-can-to-express-future-ability) **2.** [How would you use “can” in a future sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41602/how-would-you-use-can-in-a-future-sentence) **3.** [Is the usage “can able to” wrong?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/is-the-usage-can-able-to-wrong-i-believe-its-wrong-but-where-can-i-find-som?rq=1)

Comment: **4.** [“will be able to” vs. “can”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26433/will-be-able-to-vs-can) **5.** [“Will be able to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/will-be-able-to)  **6**.[Future Tense of Modal Verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229566/future-tense-of-modal-verbs)

Comment: @rogermue Was your omission of the modals’ defectiveness at forming *-ing* progressives an accidental or a willing one? :)

Comment: @tchrist  -  Oh, really, I forgot that. Never in my life have I thought of a form like *I'm canning.

Comment: @rogermue Yeah, I'm (willing to bet / I will bet) that you can only do that with this "funny" kind of *will*.

Answer (score 8):

The word *can* comes to us from the Old English *cunnan*, to know, which belongs to a Germanic-language class of verbs called "preterite-present."  These verbs have a preterite (i.e., past tense) inflective pattern in the present tense.  In English, the verb is defective, in that it has only the present and past forms (the latter being *could*) and no future form.  The verb is used modally, i.e., as an auxiliary with other verbs to express aspect or mood.  In the case of *can*, that aspect is ability.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Is there a hint of a future tense, though, in phrases like *we can jog tomorrow*? I know it can be construed as *we **are** able to jog tomorrow* - the question is whether it may be rendered as *we **will be** able to jog tomorrow*.

Comment: @Lawrence You're right that *can* may be used in sentences that express future time, but it's probably better to separate time and tense.  The latter references verb form.  Speaking strictly (like Araucaria below), tense refers to inflection.  Speaking loosely, tense includes predicates with auxiliaries *will*, *have*, and *had*.  *Can* is neither inflected nor combinable with these modals (see Araucaria below).  Instead it gives the aspect of ability.  You have to rely on other means to express future sense, like *tomorrow*.

Answer (score 2):

English has only two tenses a present tense and a past tense. We often use the modal verb *will* to express futurity in English. However, there are many other means of doing this, for example by using present continuous, *going-to*, and even the present simple. We also often use the modal verb *can* to talk about the future too.

However, we cannot use the verb modal verb *can* and the modal verb *will* in the same verb phrase. The reason for this is that we cannot use two modal verbs together. The verb after a modal verb must always be in the plain form (the "infinitive"). However modal verbs have no plain form, so this is not possible. This isn't something special about the verbs *can* and *will* in particular, although this example is very commonly discussed. It applies to any of the modal verbs. So, for example, in English, we cannot say:

- *You might must go there tomorrow.
- *You will must leave before the end of the concert.
- *You shall can speak English perfectly when you finish this course.

These sentences are all ungrammatical because they contain two modal verbs.

In answer to the Original Poster's question then. English has no future tense, we need to use special ways of talking about the future. We can use the verb *can* to talk about the future. We can also use the verb *will* to talk about the future. However, we cannot use *can* and *will* together:

- We can go for  dinner after the meeting.
- We will go for dinner after the meeting.
- *We will can go for dinner after the meeting. (ungrammatical)

Comment: Of course, in actual fact, we can use any of the modal verbs to talk about the future!